# Por que a palavra cínico é usado para indicar uma pessoa falsa/descarada?

Tags: etimologia, localização, origem-histórica

Hoje em português uma pessoa *"cínica"*, seria um pessoa *"falsa"* ou que tem atitude *"descarada*".

Já no inglês a palavra *"cynicism"* é uma atitude ou estado de espírito caracterizado por uma desconfiança geral dos motivos dos outros e acreditam que os seres humanos são egoístas por natureza.

O que levou a diferença do sentido contemporâneo desta palavra?

---

Currently in portuguese a person is said to be *"cínica"* ("cynical" equivalent in english) if they are pretending to be something they are not, even though of course other people know the truth.

In english, the word "cynicism" is an attitude or state of mind characterized by a general distrust of the motives of others who believe that human beings are selfish by nature.

What made the difference in the contemporary sense of the word?

Comment: Não é uma resposta, mas dê uma olhada em https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinismo

Comment: Aqui em Portugal o significado é o mesmo que no Brasil.

Comment: Bom saber @JorgeB. Notei a diferença ao assistir um filme e um seriado, aonde os protagonistas eram pessoas pessimistas e eram chamados de "Cínicos", fiquei sem entender e quando pesquisei percebi que o uso é bem diferente, ao menos pra mim parecem duas coisas bem distintas... PT/BR: Pessoa falsa e descarada, EN/GB: Pessoa que vê as coisas de maneira negativa.

Comment: A descrição EN para mim traduz-se em **pessimista**.

Comment: @JorgeB. editei a pergunta removendo sobre pt e br e adicionei o `pessimista` - Grato!

Comment: If you say "in other words", it's like saying they are equivalent, but cynicism and pessimism are quite different in English. Also, "pretended" can't be used as a post-fix adjective like that...and I don't really get what the word means from your first sentence. Finally, I'm going to go ahead and put the Portuguese word in the English part and vice versa; hope that's okay.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento  Não se escrevem os nomes dos idiomas **sem** letras maiúsculas —  ou seja, como *português* e *inglés*? Será que isso varia entre Portugal e Brasil?

Comment: @tchrist em todos aqui eu escrevi com a inicial em Maisculo :) Agora estou em duvida. Nunca vi nenhum padrão, você poderia formular uma pergunta?

Comment: O padrão é mesmo em minúsculas como disse o @tchrist, Guilherme. http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/422

Comment: @Guilherme, parabéns pela questão intrigante. Foi de longe a que me deu mais luta. Acho que o título podia ser mais explícito, por exemplo:  _"Cynic" and the Portuguese "Cínico" share the same origin but have different meanings. Why?_ As it stands, it is not clear you're asking about the difference between Portugese and English. I can do that myself if you like.

Comment: Em inglês, [cynical](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/cynical) não é bem o mesmo que pessimista, embora se aproxime disso. Aprendi agora que a palavra portuguesa não signifique o mesmo. :o

Answer (score 13):

**PORTUGUESE (in English below)**

***Cínico*** e os seus cognatos ingleses ***cynic*** (substantivo) e ***cynical*** (adjetivo) vão buscar os seus significados diferentes a diversos aspetos da doutrina e prática dos ***Antigos Cínicos***, os adeptos do [Antigo Cinismo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinismo), uma corrente filosófica iniciada na Grécia Antiga com [Antístenes (446-366 AC)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%ADstenes), discípulo de Sócrates, e [Diógenes de Sinope (404-323 AC)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di%C3%B3genes_de_Sinope), o mais famoso dos Antigos Cínicos.

Os Antigos Cínicos, [bem explicados na Internet Encyclopedia of Philosphy](http://www.iep.utm.edu/cynics/#H5), defendiam uma vida de acordo com a natureza, caraterizada por razão, autossuficiência, liberdade e indiferença perante as vicissitudes da vida. Isto levava-os a adotar uma vida de pobreza e trabalho duro: só assim poderiam ser autossuficientes e livres, por não estarem dependentes dos serviços de escravos ou dos favores dos poderosos. Isto permitia-lhes nomeadamente liberdade de pensamento e de expressão, pois não tinham que se preocupar com as opiniões dos outros. Estas duas anedotas acerca de Diógenes de Sinope são provavelmente inventadas mas ainda assim reveladoras:

> Alexandre o Grande (356-323 AC), o senhor da Grécia e arredores, vai visitar [Diógenes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di%C3%B3genes_de_Sinope), que vive num grande vaso, e pergunta-lhe o que é que ele, Alexandre, pode fazer por Diógenes. Diógenes responde que Alexandre se pode desviar para não lhe tapar o sol.
>
> O filósofo Platão (cerca de 425-347/8 AC) encontra [Diógenes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di%C3%B3genes_de_Sinope) a lavar alfaces bravas e diz-lhe, “Se tivesses cultivado o favor de Dionísio [tirano de Siracusa], não terias agora que lavar alfaces.” Responde Diógenes, “Se tivesses lavado alfaces, não terias agora que cultivar o favor de Dionísio.”

Esta autossuficiência e liberdade permitia aos Antigos Cínicos criticar abertamente tudo e todos. O seu método favorito era o escárnio. Criticavam nomeadamente as preocupações das pessoas com a obtenção de riquezas, poder e reputação, pois consideravam estas preocupações vãs e fúteis e um obstáculo ao florescimento humano. Escarneciam também de muitas convenções socias e mandamentos religiosos que consideravam sem fundamento natural, e agiam em conformidade, chegando ao ponto de defecar e ter relações sexuais em público. A palavra *cínico* tem origem na palavra grega para *cão*, e era um nome que o Antigos Cínicos adotaram com orgulho.

As ideias e modos de vida dos Antigos Cínicos suscitaram sempre interesse e alguma admiração, e foi a partir do século XVIII, com uma discussão mais alargada das suas ideias, que a palavra *cínico* começou a ser usada com outros significados, baseados num ou noutro aspeto particular das suas ideias e vidas. Isto vem bem explicado em [*Cynicism Then and Now* de John Christian Laursen](http://www.academicpublishingplatforms.com/downloads/pdfs/iris/volume2/201201031003_IRIS_Vol1_No2_2009_11.pdf).

O Antigo Cínico criticava as pessoas por regerem as suas vidas por preocupações fúteis com riquezas, reputação e convenções sociais sem valor. O termo inglês [*cynic*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/cynic?q=cynic) exagera e deturpa este aspeto para passar a significar uma pessoa que acredita que os outros são sempre motivados por egoísmo: futilidade passa a egoísmo. Este pessimismo relativamente às motivações humanas estende-se, no outro significado de *cynic*, a um pessimismo mais geral.

No Português, alguns dos significados de [*cínico*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/c%C3%ADnico) são impudico, obsceno, desavergonhado, descarado. (Eu não sabia isto, mas vem em todos os dicionários.) Isto vem diretamente de os Antigos Cínicos desdenharem e violarem convenções sociais e religiosas e do seu hábito de criticar e escarnecer toda a gente.

Já o outro significado em Português, *hipócrita* e *fingido*, que não vem em todos os dicionários, tem explicação menos óbvia. Curiosamente *cinismo* já apareceu associado a *hipocrisia* na língua inglesa, quando [Edmund Burke (1729-97)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Burke) chamou a [Rousseau (1712-78)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Jacques_Rousseau) cínico e o acusou de ser hipócrita e fingido. As ideias de Rousseau tinham muito do Antigo Cinismo, mas ao contrário dos Antigos Cínicos Rousseau não abdicou da sua riqueza e posição social para viver na pobreza e de acordo com a natureza. Já na antiguidade Luciano (cerca de 120-90) observou que havia mais Cínicos falsos do que genuínos. Estes Cínicos falsos, que defendiam os ideais do Antigo Cinismo só da boca para fora, parecem ser a melhor explicação para o moderno significado de hipócrita no Português.

Outras línguas apresentam ainda significados algo diferentes para os seus cognatos de *cínico*. Em Francês, [Larousse define *cynique*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cynique/21363?q=cynique#21240) como quem reconhece com insolência, e considera natural, uma conduta contrária às convenções socias e regras morais. Em Alemão, a [definição do Duden de *zynisch*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zynisch) é (1) que ofende e escarnece a decência de maneira cruel e (2) que exprime uma atitude insensível, impiedosa e desdenhosa dos valores e vida humana, a qual, especialmente em certas situações, é sentida como agonística, paradoxal e ofensiva e desdenhosa para com os sentimentos de alguém.

Curiosamente *cínico* já tem sido usado, ainda que raramente, em Português com um significado aparentemente próximo do inglês. Os exemplos seguintes vêm do [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), e infelizmente nem sempre consegui identificar a fonte convenientemente.

*Vamos ter um projeto inicial, vamos discutir isso no Brasil. Agora, não me pergunte se vai dar certo ou não vai, não sei. Sou meio cético. Mas não sou **cínico**, estou esperando que dê.* ([Roberto Requião](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberto_Requi%C3%A3o).)

*Daqui por diante começa uma era nova na minha vida. O Doutor Rodrigo Cambará vai morrer na fogueira. Um outro Rodrigo nascerá. Um Rodrigo **cínico**, realista, sem sonhos nem ideais.* ([Érico Veríssimo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89rico_Ver%C3%ADssimo), [*O Tempo e o Vento*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Tempo_e_o_Vento), parte 3, tomo 2, 1961.)

*[O]s cidadãos desenvolveram um prazer quase **cínico** de desancar nos políticos à refeição* (O Natal que se adivinha (ou se avizinha), 22 Maio 97.)

*[U]m verismo céptico, quase **cínico** por vezes* ([Jornal português?] Público, 1996.)

*Falo contigo - replicou Paulo. - Contigo, homem esquecido do coração. Contigo que não és um cético e sim um **cínico**.* ([Bruno Henrique de Almeida Seabra](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Autor:Bruno_Seabra), ¨*Paulo*, 1862.)

**ENGLISH**

The Portuguese word ***cínico*** (noun and adjective) and its English cognates ***cynic*** (noun) and ***cynical*** (adjective) got their meanings from various aspects of the ***Ancient Cynics'*** doctrine and practice. The Ancient Cynics were the followers of the [***Ancient Cyninicism***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynicism_(philosophy)), a philosophical school founded in Ancient Greece by [Anthisthenes (446-366)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisthenes), a disciple of Socrates, and [Diogenes of Sinope (404-323)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogenes_of_Sinope), the most famous of all the Ancient Cynics.

The Ancient Cynics are [well explained at Internet Encyclopedia of Philosphy](http://www.iep.utm.edu/cynics/#H5). They defended a way of live in accordance to nature. This would include reason, self-sufficiency, freedom, and indifference to the misfortunes of life. To achieve this they followed a live of poverty and hard work: this would be the only way to be self-sufficient and free, for they would not depend on the service of the slave or the favour of the powerful. This allowed them, among other things, freedom of thought and expression, for they need not care about what other people thought. These two anecdotes about Diogenes of Sinope are probably made up, but they tell us how the Ancient Cynics liked to see themselves:

> Alexander the Great (356-323 AC), overlord of Greece and beyond, calls at [Diogenes], who lives in a big tub, and asks him what he, Alexander, could do for Diogenes. Diogenes replied that Alexander could step out of his sunlight.
>
> The philosopher Plato (circa 425 – 347/8 BC) finds [Diogenes] washing wild lettuce and tells him “Had you paid court to Dionysius (tyrant of Syracuse), you wouldn’t now be washing lettuces.” Diogenes] replies, “If you had washed lettuces, you wouldn’t have paid court to Dionysius.”

This self-sufficiency and freedom allowed the Ancient Cynics to openly criticise everything and everyone. Scorn was their favourite method. They would criticise people’s concerns with wealth, power, and reputation, for they thought these concerns vain and futile and an obstacle to human flourishment. They would scorn social conventions and religious prescriptions, which they considered without natural foundation, and they would act accordingly, going as far as to defecate and masturbate in public. The word *cynic* originates in the Greek word for *dog*, a name the Ancient Cynics proudly adopted.

The Ancient Cynics’ ideas and way of life have always aroused interest and even some admiration. In the 18th century they became more widely known and discussed, and it was then that the word *cynic* began to acquire other meanings based on one or other aspect of the Ancient Cynics’ thought and practice. This topic is discussed in [*Cynicism Then and Now* de John Christian Laursen](http://www.academicpublishingplatforms.com/downloads/pdfs/iris/volume2/201201031003_IRIS_Vol1_No2_2009_11.pdf).

The Ancient Cynic criticised people for going through life guided by futile concerns with wealth, reputation, and worthless conventions. The English word [***cynic***](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/cynic?q=cynic) exaggerates and misrepresents this and takes on the meaning of someone who believes others are mainly guided by selfishness: futility becomes selfishness. This pessimism as to people’s motivations then extends to pessimism in general, which is another modern meaning of the word *cynic*.

In Portuguese, some of the meanings of [***cínico***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/c%C3%ADnico) are impudent, obscene, shameless, and brazen. This comes directly from the Ancient Cynics’ disdain for and violation of social and religious conventions and their habit of criticising and scorning everybody.

The other meaning of the Portuguese *cynic* is hypocrite and insincere. This has a less obvious explanation. Interestingly enough *cynicism* has been used in association with *hypocrisy* in the English Language, when [Edmund Burke (1729-97)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Burke) said [Rousseau (1712-78)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Jacques_Rousseau) was a cynic and went on to accuse him of hypocrisy and insincerity. There was much of Ancient Cynicism in Rousseau’s ideas, but unlike the Ancient Cynics Rousseau did not forgo his wealth and social status to live a life of poverty according to nature. In ancient times Luciano (circa 120 – 90 BC) had observed already that there were more fake Cynics than genuine ones. These fake Cynics, who profess the ideals of Ancient Cynicism in words only, seem to be the best explanation for the meaning of hypocrite in modern Portuguese.

The cognates of *cynic* in other languages have yet other meanings. In French [Larousse defines *cynique*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cynique/21363?q=cynique#21240) as someone who insolently acknowledges and consider normal a behaviour that is contrary to social conventions and moral rules. In German [Duden defines *zynisch*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zynisch) as Expressing an insensitive, uncompassionate, attitude that disdains human values and human life, and which, especially in specific matters, is felt as antagonistic, paradoxical, and as disdaining and hurting someone’s feelings.

Interestingly the Portuguese word *cínico* has been used already, even if rarely, with a meaning apparently close to that of English *cynic*. The following examples come from this [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), and unfortunately I could not identify the source of some of them.

*Vamos ter um projeto inicial, vamos discutir isso no Brasil. Agora, não me pergunte se vai dar certo ou não vai, não sei. Sou meio cético. Mas não sou **cínico**, estou esperando que dê.* (*We are going to have a first project, we are going to discuss this in Brazil. Now, do not ask me whether it is going to work or not; I do not know. I am somewhat sceptical. But I am not a **cynic**, I hope it will work.*) ([Roberto Requião](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberto_Requi%C3%A3o).)

*Daqui por diante começa uma era nova na minha vida. O Doutor Rodrigo Cambará vai morrer na fogueira. Um outro Rodrigo nascerá. Um Rodrigo **cínico**, realista, sem sonhos nem ideais.* (*Now is the start of a new era in my life. Doctor Rodrigo Cambará will burn at the stake. Another Rodrigo will be born. A cynical and down-to-earth Rodrigo, with no dreams or ideals,*) ([Érico Veríssimo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erico_Verissimo), [*O Tempo e o Vento/The Time and the Wind*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Tempo_e_o_Vento), part 3, tomo 2, 1961.)

*[O]s cidadãos desenvolveram um prazer quase **cínico** de desancar nos políticos à refeição*. (*Citizens have acquired an almost **cynical** liking for lambasting politicians at meal times.*) (O Natal que se adivinha (ou se avizinha), 22 Maio 97.)

*[U]m verismo céptico, quase **cínico** por vezes* (*A skeptical verism, almost **cynical** at times.*) (Portuguese daily Público, 1996.)

*Falo contigo - replicou Paulo. - Contigo, homem esquecido do coração. Contigo que não és um cético e sim um **cínico**.* (*I am talking to you — replied Paulo. — To you, who have forgotten the heart. To you, who are not a skeptic but a **cynic**.*)  ([Bruno Henrique de Almeida Seabra](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Autor:Bruno_Seabra), ¨*Paulo*, 1862.)

Comment: "*Já o outro significado em Português, hipócrita e fingido, que não vem em todos os dicionários, tem explicação menos óbvia.*" Interessante - para mim, "cínico" e "hipócrita" são descritores mutuamente excludentes: o cínico faz coisas chocantes sem se preocupar com a opinião alheia, o hipócrita faz coisas chocantes disfarçando-as para que pareçam aceitáveis ou até comendáveis. "*Sinceridade é a linha imaginária que separa a hipocrisia do cinismo*", por exemplo.