# Os nomes de linguagens devem ser escritos com maiúsculas ou minúsculas?

Tags: maiúsculas-e-minúsculas

Em inglês, o nome das linguagens é escrito com letras maiúsculas:

> This is a site for people willing to discuss and learn the Portuguese language. However, the site's interface is in English.

Entretanto, pelo meu entendimento, na língua portuguesa apenas nomes próprios (que são substantivos) e a primeira letra de cada frase deveriam iniciar com letras maiúsculas. E isso não inclui nomes de linguagens, que são adjetivos, quando estão no meio de uma frase.

Entretanto, vejo até mesmo nesta comunidade, casos aonde "Português" e "Inglês" são escritos com letras maiúsculas. E até já tomei um revert parcial do Gabe no meta do SOpt uma vez por causa disso.

Assim sendo, faz sentido escrever-se o nome das linguagens com letra maiúsculas quando não estão no início da frase? Se sim, porque?

Comment: Tenho quase a certeza que é com minúsculas, ss não consigo encontrar uma fonte.

Comment: @someonewithpc Por que você apagou a sua resposta?

Comment: Porque não tenho uma fonte para citar, mas se quiser posso trazê-la de novo

Comment: Os nomes de línguas e nacionalidades (mas não de países) são escritos **sem** letras maiúsculas. Por exemplo: [1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_portuguesa), [2](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa), [3](http://www.dn.pt/inicio/globo/interior.aspx?content_id=4685400), [4](http://www.dn.pt/inicio/globo/interior.aspx?content_id=4685011).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Com iniciais minúsculas.

Segundo o [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990):

> BASE XIX: DAS MINÚSCULAS E MAIÚSCULAS
>
> 1.    A letra minúscula inicial é usada:
>
> a) Ordinariamente, em todos os vocábulos da língua nos usos correntes.
>
> b) Nos nomes dos dias, meses, estações do ano: segunda-feira; outubro; primavera.
>
> c) Nos bibliónimos/bibliônimos (após o primeiro elemento, que é com maiúscula, os demais vocábulos podem ser escritos   com minúscula, salvo nos nomes próprios nele contidos, tudo em grifo): O Senhor do Paço de Ninães, O Senhor do paço de Ninães, Menino de Engenho, Menino de engenho, Árvore e Tambor ou Árvore e tambor.
>
> d) Nos usos de fulano, sicrano, beltrano.
>
> e) Nos pontos cardeais (mas não nas suas abreviaturas): norte, sul (mas: SW sudoeste).
>
> f) Nos axiónimos/axiônimos e hagiónimos/hagiônimos (opcionalmente, neste caso, também com maiúscula): senhor doutor   Joaquim da Silva, bacharel Mário Abrantes, o Cardeal Bembo; santa Filomena (ou Santa Filomena).
>
> g) Nos nomes que designam domínios do saber, cursos e disciplinas (opcionalmente, também com maiúscula): português   (ou Português), matemática (ou Matemática); línguas e literaturas modernas (ou Línguas e Literaturas Modernas).

Entendo que os nomes das línguas se encaixe no contexto de "domínio do saber". O [Acordo de 1943](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&id=16-49&version=1943) já dizia algo semelhante, e a lista de casos de uso obrigatório de iniciais maiúsculas não menciona nada sobre nomes de idiomas.

Comment: "Acordo Ortográfico" ou "acordo ortográfico"?

Comment: Se não me engano essa é uma fonte que eu vi e é referente ao acordo de 1943, não é assim? Pode postar o link?

Comment: @someone Estou na rua agora, mais tarde acho o link e te digo. Posso ter errado a fonte, mas tenho certeza de que é em minúsculas, pelo menos no Brasil

Comment: Tem razão @someonewithpc, eu citei o acordo de 43 sem perceber: http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&id=16-49&version=1943. Vou procurar outra referência.

Comment: @someonewithpc Atualizei com base no Acordo mais recente.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, penso que ao se considerar o uso opcional para inicial maiúscula ou minúscula nas disciplinas, a escolha é do produtor textual de dar ou não o destaque, pois ao optar pela maiúscula estará singularizando a palavra. Ex. O Português europeu é diferente do Português brasileiro. Liberdade, minha gente! O Novo Acordo veio para facilitar e regularizar o uso respeitando as culturas.