# Does "rapariga" have a pejorative connotation in ptPT?

Tags: significado, diferenças-transatlânticas

**In ptBR**, "rapariga" is primarily used as a synonym for "concubina", "amante" or "meretriz" [**(Aurélio)**](http://www.dicionariodoaurelio.com/rapariga) and I often heard it when I was a child, during the 1960s. Nowadays it is certainly outdated and few people use it. Then again, when I visit Portugal I hear it and don't perceive any pejorative meaning.  Depending on context, can it mean "meretriz" or "concubina" **in ptPT**?

ps - Even though "meretriz" comes as number 4 definition in "Aurelio Online", I always heard it as a pejorative.

Comment: I think "Aurélio" is usually used to refer to the "Dicionário Aurélio" published by Editora Positivo. You link to "Dicionário **do** Aurélio", which seems to have borrowed the name, but otherwise has nothing to do with "The" Aurélio. In fact, "Dicionário do Aurélio" seems to be suspiciously similar to the Dicionário Priberam. (Compare [the former](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/rapariga) to [the latter](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/rapariga).)

Comment: Where in Brazil do you hear _rapariga_ as a synonym for _concubina, amante, meretriz_?

Comment: @Earthliŋ   As I said before, I haven't heard it for a long time. Whatever the  meaning, the word is outdated.  About 40 to 55 years ago I used to hear it in Rio de Janeiro and Espírito Santo states.

Comment: @Earthliŋ  When I mention "Aurélio" without a link I refer to "Novo Dicionário Aurélio da Língua Portuguesa, Editora Nova Fronteira, printed Edition".  All times when I provided a link, I assumed it was the same dictionary.  I will check that and try to find the real Aurélio online.

Comment: Ok, then we're talking about the same Aurélio, because it was published by Nova Fronteira before 2003 and after by Positivo from 2003 until now. Take a look, but I don't think the real Aurélio is available online.

Comment: It is not pejorative, I believe that most people do not know the meaning of this word, so people use incorrectly. Similar to this: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/25/meaning-of-the-words-cynicism-and-cynical-in-different-regions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*(this answer describes European usage, since that's what you ask about)*

You have two questions there:

1. whether it can mean "prostitute" and
2. whether it has a pejorative connotation.

For instance, *prostituta* or *meretriz* just mean "prostitute" and have little or no negative connotation, whereas *puta* and (to a lesser extent) *rameira* do have a negative connotation and (generally) also mean "prostitute". If you wanted to use a pejorative word for someone sexually promiscuous but that's not a prostitute, you could use *galdéria* ou *puta*.

But in the case of *rapariga*, the answer is **no** to both -- it doesn't have a pejorative connotation and it doesn't mean "female prostitute".

(I was going to say its usage is comparable to *moça* -- which is a bit old-fashioned in Portugal  --, but then Priberam lists it as being a synonym for *meretriz* in Brazil; it seems every word for "girl" means *prostitute* in Brazil :) ).

The word for *girl* that we in Portugal generally use to refer to prostitutes is *menina*, and even then it needs to be clear from the context (e.g. "ir às meninas") and it doesn't have a pejorative connotation (it's actually euphemistic).

Comment: What other words for _girl_ mean prostitute in Brazil?

Comment: @Jacinto rapariga (de programa), and moça. I don't think "menina" is negative, but we'll need trans-atlantic confirmation. :)

Comment: @Jacinto   In addition to "puta" which is the most vulgar of them, a prostitute in Rio de Janeiro is usually referred to as: garota de programa, mulher de programa and prostitute, of course.  These are current usage and are not offensive.  Some people also say piranha, vadia, mulher da vida, when they want to give a negative connotation.  Words like rameira, meretriz and rapariga are outdated. As for "menina" it's rarely used ("onde é que ficam as meninas aqui nessa cidade?"  "Onde ficam as mulheres?" a foreigner might ask.)

Comment: Moça doesn't have a pejorative connotation in Brazil

Comment: @ANeves  We never refer to a prostitute as "uma moça".  Moça in Brazil means "a young woman, under the age of 18 usually" or it can also mean "a virgin, a woman who never had sexual intercourse"  but the latter is outdated as more and more young women engage in sexual activity earlier.

Comment: _Garota de programa_  etc. is very different from _garota_, just like the meaning of _menina_  changes quite a bit from _ir às meninas_ to _a menina dá-me licença_. We also say _mulher da vida_, but _mulher_ is of course just _woman_.

Comment: Math and @Centaurus , I stand corrected. :) I suggest you contact [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mo%C3%A7a).

Comment: @ANeves  As far as usage of a word in Portugal is concerned, I trust you much more than I trust any dictionary.

Comment: Em algumas regiões do Brasil, principalmente no Sul pode significar apenas jovem moça. No norte e nordeste pode significar prostituta. Mas o mais comum é que signifique dependendo do contexto "mulher fácil e volúvel", geralmente quando se insinuam/flertam/se evolvem com o acompanhante de alguém.

Answer (score 6):

Just to try to clear some of the confusion with the dictionary definitions...

> ### Aurélio
>
> #### rapariga
>
> [De *rapaz*, mas de formação obsc.]
> *Substantivo feminino.*
>
> 1. *P. us. no Brasil* Mulher nova; moça: *[...]*
> 2. *P. us. no Brasil* Adolescente do sexo feminino.
> 3. *Lus.* Moça do campo
> 4. *Bras. N. N.E. MG GO* Amante² (6) ou concubina.
> 5. *Bras. N. N.E. MG GO* Meretriz. *[...]*
>
> ---
>
> ### Priberam
>
> #### ra·pa·ri·ga
>
> (origem obscura)
> substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Mulher nova. =<sub><sup>JOVEM, MOÇA</sup></sub>
> 2. Mulher entre a infância e a adolescência. = <sub><sup>MOÇA</sup></sub>
> 3. Menina pequena.
> 4. [Brasil]  Meretriz.

It appears that according to the ptPT dictionary *Priberam*, **the pejorative usage is restricted to Brazil**. (The *Dicionário **do** Aurélio* you link to is based on the ptPT *Dicionário Priberam* and not on the ptBR *Dicionário Aurélio*.)

Moreover, the ptBR dictionary Aurélio is more precise about where in Brazil *rapariga* is used pejoratively: primarily in the North (AC, AP, AM, PA, RO, RR, TO) and North-East (AL, BA, CE, MA, PB, PE, PI, RN, SE) regions, together with the states of Minas Gerais (MG) and Goiás (GO). That is, here:

[image: rapariga]

<sup>(image adapted from [SVG file](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Brazilian_States.svg) on Wikimedia)</sup>

In other areas of Brazil it can also be used to mean "young woman" or "female adolescent", but this usage is rare (*P. us. no Brasil* = Pouco usado no Brasil).

---

### tl;dr

> Does “rapariga” have a pejorative connotation in ptPT?

No, *rapariga* does **not** have a pejorative connotation in ptPT.

> ps - Even though "meretriz" comes as number 4 definition in "Aurelio Online", I always heard it as a pejorative.

This online dictionary "Dicionário do Aurélio" doesn't have anything to do with Aurélio, but is likely based on the ptPT dictionary "Priberam", so one shouldn't expect it to give definitions pertaining to Brazilian Portuguese.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site where you got that map?

Comment: All the information you provided, Earthling, is great, but left me a bit confused. ptPT and ptBR Priberams give the same definitions for _rapariga_. (I think the only difference between the versions is in spelling.) And I think it is Priberam that is based on other dictionaries, not the other way round. And, Centaurus, I think Earthling just coloured a map with the information from Aurélio.

Comment: @Jacinto Sorry, I lost you. What do you mean `ptPT and ptBR Priberams`? I quoted Priberam as an ptPT dictionary and Aurélio as ptBR dictionary. Both dictionaries agree that the pejorative usage of _rapariga_ is restricted to Brazil. Aurélio is more precise as to where in Brazil this usage is most common.

Comment: @Jacinto I added a tl;dr at the end. Does this make my answer any clearer?

Comment: I see what you mean: Priberam is published in Portugal. There are two versions of Priberam, ptPT and ptBR, which you can choose, but I think the only difference is spelling (say gênero and género). But since they give meanings that are current in Brazil only, at least they attempt to be a dictionary of the Portuguses language, no matter where it is used. Now, I've seen entries in Priberam that appear to come straight out of other dictionaries, so not sure who's copying whom in this case. So you have a paper Aurélio, do you? it it's online you could include a link.

Comment: You say Aurélio online does not include ptBR meanings, but it does: _meretriz_; the problem is it gives no information about where it's used (which Priberam does to some extent in this case). The last paragraph in your tl;dr just expands on something you have above the map. If it were my answer,  I would edit that if necessary; I wouldn't repeat. What is tl;dr, btw?

Comment: Yes, what does tl;dr stand for?

Comment: @Jacinto & Centaurus. tl;dr (or TLDR, tldr, ...) stands for "too long, didn't read". It originates from editor shorthand for a text that is too long for the editor to read/digest, but is sometimes (mis?)used to give a summary of the post when it's long and convoluted. For more info, consult your favourite web search engine =)

Comment: *together with the states of Minas Gerais (MG)*  - eu resido neste estado e este termo é pouquíssimo usado com significado pejorativo. Acredito que seja conhecido assim apenas nas proximidades do norte do estado(por fazer fronteira com a Bahia), mas na grande maioria das cidades, creio que seja muito pouco usada a palavra.