# Rapariga: Uso pejorativo e chulo no nordeste do Brasil

Tags: português-brasileiro

O feminino de rapaz é rapariga, ou rapacina em galego. Como se explica seu uso chulo no nordeste brasileiro?

Comment: O Priberam tem [uma referência ao usu brasileiro](https://dicionario.priberam.org/rapariga), mas sem explicação da origem.

Comment: Acredito que rapariga é pejorativo em quase todo o Brasil. Pelo menos no Sul também é

Comment: pergunta relacionada...https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/does-rapariga-have-a-pejorative-connotation-in-ptpt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does "rapariga" have a pejorative connotation in ptPT?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/does-rapariga-have-a-pejorative-connotation-in-ptpt)

Comment: Infelizmente, com certas conotações e em certos contextos, quase *qualquer* palavra que signifique pessoa do sexo feminino pode ser pejorativo, quer por significar "prostituta", quer por denotar algum tipo de inferioridade (e.g., "mulherzinha" como medroso ou fraco). Mas eu não diria que "rapariga" chega a ser chulo, apenas pejorativo.

Comment: Concordo. Chulo é muito forte. E qualquer palavra feminina pode se transformar de alguma forma pejorativa. Lembrei que no Rio Grande do Sul usamos *prima* como sinônimo de prostituta.

Comment: @stafusa como foi decidido [pela comunidade](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/67/153) as perguntas são fechadas como duplicadas mas convém garantir a tradução da pergunta original e das respostas.

Comment: @jorgeb Bom ponto.

Comment: Em Portugal rapariga não é pejorativo